# <ErrorMessage /> not rendering despite error <Dropdown /> being left blank

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, primereact

I'm complicating matters by trying to use PrimeReact `<InputText />` and `<Dropdown />` with the `<Field />` component.

- The `<InputText />` works as expected with the `<ErrorMessage />` in that when you enter the field and leave it, the error message pops up saying the field is required.
- The `<Dropdown />` does not render the `<ErrorMessage />`. No matter what I've tried, if you enter the field and leave it without specifying anything, the error message will not pop up and it doesn't even trigger the `validationSchema()`. I've added `onBlur` to the `<Dropdown />` which triggers when you leave it, but it does not trigger `validationSchema()` like `<InputText />` does.

```
// Import React Libraries
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

//Prime React Imports
import { Dialog } from 'primereact/dialog';
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown';
import { InputText } from 'primereact/inputtext';
import {
  FileUpload,
  FileUploadProps,
  FileUploadRemoveParams,
} from 'primereact/fileupload';

//Formik Imports and Packeges
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, FieldProps } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const ProductUpload = (props: any) => {
  const formRefs: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  const fileUploadRef = useRef(null);

  //Validation Schema using Yup
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    prodId: Yup.string().required('Field Required'),
    active: Yup.string().required('Field Required'),
  });

  const onSubmit = () => {
    // stuff
  };

  const itemTemplate = (file: File, props: FileUploadProps) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Formik
          key={file.name}
          innerRef={(ref) => (formRefs[file.name] = ref)}
          initialValues={{
            prodId: '',
            active: '',
          }}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            //@ts-ignore
            onSubmit(e, props, file);
          }}
          validateOnBlur={true}
          isInitialValid={false}
        >
          {({ isValid }) => (
            <Form>
              {/* This works as expected */}
              <h3 style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }}>{file.name}</h3>
              <div className='product-import-field-row'>
                <div className='field-error-col'>
                  <Field
                    name='prodId'
                    render={({ field }: FieldProps) => (
                      <InputText
                        id='prodId'
                        type='text'
                        {...field}
                        placeholder='Enter Product ID'
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name='prodId'
                    component='div'
                    style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5px' }}
                  />
                </div>

                {/* This does not */}
                <div className='field-error-col'>
                  <Field
                    name='active'
                    render={({ field }: FieldProps) => (
                      <Dropdown
                        style={{ minWidth: '155px' }}
                        options={[
                          {
                            label: 'Active',
                            value: true,
                          },
                          {
                            label: 'Inactive',
                            value: false,
                          },
                        ]}
                        {...field}
                        placeholder='Select Status'
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name='active'
                    component='div'
                    style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5px' }}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Dialog
        header='Upload and Attach File'
        visible={props.show}
        onHide={() => props.onHide()}
        style={{ width: '90vw', height: '90vh' }}
      >
        <FileUpload
          ref={fileUploadRef}
          name='files'
          url='/upload' // Replace with your upload API endpoint
          multiple
          //@ts-ignore
          itemTemplate={itemTemplate}
          //uploadHandler={onSubmit}
          customUpload
          uploadOptions={uploadOptions}
          emptyTemplate={
            <p className='m-0'>Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>
          }
        />
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductUpload;
```

It seems like it could be due to `<Dropdown />` and how it handles `onBlur`.

I've tried doing something like the following to force a trigger of `validationSchema()`:

```
...
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    prodId: Yup.string().required('Field Required'),
    active: Yup.string()
      .required('Field Required')
      .test({
         name: 'is-active',
         test: (value, ctx) => {
           console.log('Test function called with value:', value);
           if (value === 'invalid') {
             return ctx.createError({ message: 'Field Required' });
           } else {
             return true;
           }
         },
      }),
  });

...

                {/* This does not */}
                <div className='field-error-col'>
                  <Field
                    name='active'
                    render={({ field, form }: FieldProps) => (
                      <Dropdown
                        style={{ minWidth: '155px' }}
                        options={[
                          {
                            label: 'Active',
                            value: true,
                          },
                          {
                            label: 'Inactive',
                            value: false,
                          },
                        ]}
                        placeholder='Select Status'
                        value={field.value}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          form.setFieldValue(field.name, e.value)
                        }
                        onBlur={() => 
                          form.setFieldValue(
                            field.name,
                            field.value ? field.value : 'invalid'
                        )}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name='active'
                    component='div'
                    style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5px' }}
                  />
                </div>
...
```

And while this does for a trigger of `validationSchema`, the error message still does not render.

Styles for additional info:

```
div[role='progressbar'] {
  display: none;
}

.p-fileupload-row {
  display: block;
}

.p-fileupload .p-fileupload-content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.product-import-field-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.field-error-col {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    position: 'relative';
}
```

Suggestions for what I'm doing wrong here?